# .....Let it begin

Tags: knowledge, pattern, visual

The task is to somehow make sense of these images: each image represents a single word/noun/abbreviation except image 7 (two words). Once you've done that, replace the question marks (each question mark represents a digit).

Good luck!

[image: puzzle]

**??** *-96* , **????** *-85* , **????** *-99* , **??** *-76* , **???** *-97*

Comment: I don't want to know what image 4 really is. It scares me...

Comment: Is the question mark in image 2 related to the question marks representing the unknown digits?

Comment: :).... no it's not

Comment: don't worry @Earlien it's just jam :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to @QuantumTwinkie for the tip that the images correspond to movie titles. Edit: I swapped the intended meanings of the images so with an additional hint from the puzzler I have hopefully corrected my mistake.

I will go in order of the words corresponding to the numbers of each image, which are then used as placeholders for the question marks.

> 2 = space, 4 = jam and the movie "Space Jam" was released in -96, so putting the image number in place of the nouns of the movie title we get **?? 96 = "Space Jam" -96 = 24 -96**.

> 11 = back (of a shirt), 7 = to the, 9 = future, and "Back to the Future" was released in -85, so **???? -85 = "Back to the Future" -85 = 1179 -85**

> 3 = eyes, 10 = wide (width), 6 = shut (gesture for shut up), and "Eyes Wide Shut" was released in -99, so **???? -99 = "Eyes Wide Shut" -99 = 3106 -99**

> 12 = Titan (moon of Saturn), 8 = ic (integrated circuit) so putting the two together we get "Titanic" which was released in -97, so **??? -97 = "Titanic" -97 = 128 -97**

> 1 = taxi (the word "taxi" has been cropped out of the taxi light) and 5 = driver. Putting them together we get "Taxi Driver" released in -76 so **?? -76 = "Taxi Driver" -76 = 15 -76**

> **As an aside**: "Taxi Driver" was my first thought for the year 1976 as this was one of the most famous movies released that year but I had swapped clues 1 and 6, so I couldn't derive "Taxi Driver" from clues 5 and 6.

Comment: Ahh, nice finds!

Comment: @Derek O, Great job! You've go them all right except rot13(gur gvgyr 'qevir-va'. Gur vagraqrq nafjre jnf nabgure zbivr gvgyr gung jnf eryrnfrq gung lrne. V pna fnl gung vzntr1(oyheerq fbzrguvat abeznyyl jevggra va oynpx. Jurer qb lb abeznyyl frr guvf ynzc?) naq vzntr 5 ner pbaarpgrq. Nyfb gur 'fuhg' cneg jnf vagraqrq sbe vzntr6.

Comment: Now it looks good :)

Answer (score 8):

Guess

> A set of pictures may clue to a movie, where the numbers refer to the year of which it was released(or how many years since its release)

I do not have a great moive knowlegde, but one could be

> **Back to the Future** with clues #7, #9, and #11

Another may be

> **Space Jam** with clues #4 and #12

Another may be

> **Quiet Place** with clues #6 and #5(the guy is driving to a place?)

Other guesses include

> Clue three may refer to the word "eyes".

So,

> The numbers may be -2018(Quiet Place), -85(BttF), or -96(Space Jam)

Comment: This is a great start!

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie Your guess was correct ofc! This is indeed movie titles